# Suggest a good db structure

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using MongoDB for database and mongoose for schema definition.

I have a collection of hotels which looks like this:

```
{
  name:{
    type:string
  },
  tax:{
    type:string,
  }
  .......
  type_of_room:[{
    category:{
      type:String,
      enum: ['SINGLEA','SINGLEB','SINGLEC','DOUBLEA','DOUBLEB','DOUBLEC','TRIPLEA','TRIPLEB','TRIPLEC','QUADA','QUADB','QUADC'],
      required: true
    },
    title:{
      type:String
    }
    price:{
      type:Number,
      required:true
    }
  }]
}
```

As hotel prices are dynamic over the year I want to assign prices on each day of the year to every accommodation category.

Doing this the user dashboard can be made in a way that admin can assign prices over weeks, months, seasons quarterly or whatever way he/she wants

I don't know what should be the right structure to store this.

Suggest a good way to accommodate a structure where each accommodation can have prices for 356/366 days in a year.

Answer (score -1):

```
you need to create a CATEGORY collection, separate CATEGORY collection from main a
hotel collection. You need to read these posts. 

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-polymorphic-pattern
```

Comment: This doesn't help me in any way...

Please state why you want me to separate my collection also how do I accommodate all those 365 entries ?